# Some Algorithm on Decidablitly

Tags: computability, context-free, formal-grammars, undecidability, decision-problem

Anyone could correct me that  Why just (1) is False. i'm not sure why others are true: ( G is a Context Free Grammar). any brief description?

1. There is an algorithm that decides whether the complement of $L(G)$ (language generated by $G$) is empty or not.
2. There is an algorithm that decides whether the reverse of $L(G)$ is empty or not.
3. There is an algorithm that decides whether $L(G)$ is finite or not.
4. There is an algorithm that decides whether $L(G)$ is empty or not.

Comment: 1) You pose three questions in one post; please don't do that. 2) What, specifically, have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: BY the way, all the answers are on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language). So what's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In computability theory and computational complexity theory, an undecidable problem is a decision problem for which it is known to be impossible to construct a single algorithm that always leads to a correct yes-or-no answer.

(2) to (4) is True, because this algorithms is Decidable, and (1) is false because is not decidable. (undecidable).

Comment: Proof/reference needed.